# Safe to convert Java.sql.date to Java.util.date by up casting?

Tags: java, date, jdbc

Java.sql.date extends java.util.date, so is it save to convert between the two by casting a java.sql.date as a java.util.date?  Or is there some other way to convert them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can just upcast it.

The `java.sql.Date` is in fact nothing less or more than a representation of the SQL Date type, which has only year, month and day filled.

Answer (score 12):

You don't necessarily need to cast, you can just treat a SQL Date as if it was a util Date:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(whenever);
java.util.Date utilDate = sqlDate;
```

Compiles and runs just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Though you can easily obtain the java.sql.Date from java.util.Date, you need to be careful that java.sql.Date has only Date information minus time details.

If needed, you need to look at java.sql.Time or java.sql.Timestamp.