# How to convert Hibernate.TIMESTAMP to Date?

Tags: java, hibernate, date, timestamp

How to convert Hibernate.TIMESTAMP to java.util.Date format?

Comment: Not following exactly what you are asking.  Hibernate.TIMESTAMP represents java.sql.Timestamp which extends java.util.Date.  So it is a java.util.Date.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: Maybe this question and answer will help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165025/safe-to-convert-java-sql-date-to-java-util-date-by-up-casting

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
    if (startDate != null) {
        this.startDate = new Date(startDate.getTime());
    } else {
        this.startDate = null;
    }
}
```